# One block to subscribe to all content on site Subscription Module Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, subscriptions

I want to put a subscription block on a single page on the site that will allow users to subscribe to all content on the site by default. I a using subscriptions module.How do I achieve this?

Comment: try this module https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions

Comment: Hi Praveen, I am using subscriptions module. I want to set defaults subscription for new and existing users when they subscribe to the site that gives subscription to all content using a single block.

Comment: I am also looking for this feature

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but I think you could use the Subscription rules module: https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions_rules  and the https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link module to meet some of your need. It would involve making a view/block with the "Rules Link" that then triggered the subscription rule action to subscribe people to all of the site content, etc.